# Can not fix the order of display:flex elements

Tags: css, flexbox

```css
.test {
  display: flex;
  flex - direction: column;
  flex: 1;
  flex - wrap: wrap;
}

.break {
  flex - basis: 100 %;
  height: 0;
}

.b {
  width: 500 px;
  height: 50 px;
  border: 1 px solid red;
  flex - basis: 20 %;
  flex - wrap: nowrap;
}

.flex1 {
  display: flex;
  flex - direction: row;
}

.test2 {
  display: flex;
  flex - direction: column;
  flex - wrap: nowrap;
}

.bb {
  display: flex;
}

.flex2 {
  display: flex;
  flex - wrap: wrap;
}

.flex3 {
  display: flex;
  flex - direction: row;
  flex - wrap: wrap;
  align - items: center;
}
```

```html
<div class="test">
  <div class="flex1">
    <div class="1 b">1</div>
    <div class="2 b">1</div>
  </div>
  <div class="test2">
    <div class="flex2">
      <div class="3 b">2.1</div>
      <div class="4 b">2.2</div>
      <div class="break"></div>
      <div class="5 b bb">2.3</div>
    </div>

    <div class="flex3">
      <div class="3 b bb">3.1</div>
      <div class="break"></div>
      <div class="4 b">3.2</div>
      <div class="break"></div>
      <div class="5 b">3.3</div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

I have a problem with a display:flex when ordering the elements. I want to achieve the same thing as in the image . I want the 3.1 to be in the same row as the 2.3 and the 3.2 and the 3.3 to stay exactly the same as in the image.

[Here is the image example that I want to achieve](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6XSXB.png)

I want to achieve this behavior in the media queries, the HTML order should stay the same.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hope it helps

```css
.row {
  display: flex;
  gap: 30px;
}

.item {
  flex: 0 0 40%;
  padding: 10px;
  border: 1px solid red;
}

.column>div {
  width: 40%;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="item">1</div>
    <div class="item">1</div>
  </div>
  <div class="row">
    <div class="item">2.1</div>
    <div class="item">2.2</div>
  </div>
  <div class="row">
    <div class="item">2.3</div>
    <div class="item">3.1</div>
  </div>
  <div class="column">
    <div class="item">3.2</div>
    <div class="item">3.3</div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).